# VBA Word Macro: Save As existing .docx file name with standard prefix

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to construct a macro that takes an active document and saves it with the same file name but adds a non-variable prefix.

The document I am working with has hyperlinks, which, according to the internet, appears to be the reason I am unable to use this code:

```
Sub SaveAsDigital()
'
' Flatten Macro
'
'
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Digital_" & ActiveDocument.Name

End Sub
```

This returns Run-time Error '4198' with relates to hyperlinks being present in the document (I cannot afford to get rid of these)

Any help would be much appreciated!Thanks!

Comment: it seems to work for me,  is the hyperlinks for another document?

Comment: @Omar no hyperlinks for other documents. the file includes both Table of Contents and Table of Authorities. Additionally, there are mail merge fields throughout and cross references to appendices. It's quite the document...

Comment: If you look into that run time error it appears to have issues running for documents that have linked fields.